# calling 2 different classes with the same object

Tags: c#, arrays, class, object

I'm really new to c# programming,so please correct me if I am wrong at my terminologies.

I would just like to ask, if it is possible to use 2 different classes from the same object.the code goes like this:

```
    //from the Animal Class;
  public void Run()
  {  
     int counter = 0;
     string input = "Beagle";
     string input2 = "Fox Terrier";
    Dog[] al = new Dog[10];
    do
    {
    al[counter] = new Dog();
    al[counter].validateAnimal(input);
    al[counter] = new Breed();
    Breed br = (Breed)al[counter];
    br.validateBreed(input2);
    }while(counter < 10)
 }   
    //Dog Class
    //Dog : Animal
    public void validateDog(string In)
    {
    if(In == "Beagle")
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Ok");
    }
    }

//breed class 
// Breed : Dog
public void validateBreed(string In)
{
if(In == "Fox Terrier")
{
Console.WriteLine("Great");
}
}
```

What I want to do is run both the validateDog and validateBreed while it is being run in the main class. I also need to have Breed be a derived class of Dog,and Dog be a derived class of animal. There seems to be no syntax error. but the validateBreed doesn't show.

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Your `do while` will not end very soon. Besides that, the Dog at counter will be overwritten by a Breed at the same place. This is not C# specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> need to have Breed be a derived class of Dog

This is a wrong requirement. Breed is not a 'kind of dog', breed is a `property of Dog`.
Instead of creating a derived class, you should create a property `Breed` in `Dog` class.

You could list all available breeds in an `enum` or define a class for it.

```
public enum Breed { Beagle, Husky }

public class Dog
{
    public Dog(Breed breed)
    {
        this.Breed = breed;
    }

    public Breed Breed { get; private set; }
}
```

Notice that breed is being passed in the constructor and cannot be modified outside `Dog` class since dogs usually don't change breeds.

UPDATE:

You should post your whole code. Hard to tell what you're doing now.
From your sample this should work:

```
var breed = new Breed();
breed.validateDog("");
breed.validateBreed("");
```

as both methods are public.

You might want to define a virtual method `validate` is base class and override it in derived classes.

Comment: Oh i see.Sorry for my example.I just used the dog as an example.But let's say what if would I would run both the validateDog and validateBreed from the main class, wherein the breed is inherited from dog,and dog is inherited from animal, syntactically, what is wrong?